# CSS Solution to centring an absolutely positioned DIV inside a smaller container DIV

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is it possible to centre, horizontally and verticly a DIV with absolute positioning inside a containing div (relative positioning).

Imagine an image twice the height and width of its containment div, but is contained within the div with. Rather than show only half the image starting at the top left corner would it be possible to show the middle of the image instead without JS.

CSS,

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container > img {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Based on this example CSS you could say `top:-100px; left:-150px;` however what **if we don't know the size of the img**.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Set the image to be the `background-image` of the <div> and center align that way, vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely position a div within another div, you can only center it exactly, i.e. work out the difference between the widths of the two divs, divide it by two and have that as your left and right margin. If you want to center it dynamically (if the size of the inner div might change, for example), it has to be relatively positioned.